# Relatively formatting edit_date

Tags: edit-date

I'm inside this loop:

`{exp:channel:entries channel="people" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" status="open|closed" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes" sort="asc" orderby="people_last_name" limit="999"}`

Just about everything I'm displaying is working as expected.  At one point, I have:

```
{edit_date format="%m/%d/%y"} - {edit_date:relative}
```

`{edit_date format="%m/%d/%y"}` works fine.  `{edit_date:relative}` gets passed through as literal text.  So I get results like:

```
12/02/12 - {edit_date:relative}
```

Anyone know what I’m doing wrong, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does `{entry_date:relative}` work in the same place in the template?

Comment: It does not.  I should have thought to check that.  How do I turn it on?

Comment: Like @albuvee answered, what version of EE are you running? (Also, I can confirm that `{edit_date:relative}` actually _is_ implemented - just tried it).

Comment: That was the problem: we’re behind 2.8.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative Dates have been introduced to (native) Expression Engine in Version 2.8.

Have you checked if your Site is running on EE 2.8 or newer?

Comment: Ah!  I didn’t realize it was a new feature.  We’re behind 2.8, so that’s the problem.  Thanks!

(An EE upgrade is planned for soon.)